# Matrix Optimization for Solution of $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Assume that $\mathcal{A}$ is a convex set of square matrices of order $n$ and the equation
\begin{equation}
Ax=b, 
\end{equation}
has a single unique solution $x>\bf{0}$ for any $A\in \mathcal{A}$, where $b$ is a fixed vector.

I'm trying to minimize the sum of $x$:
\begin{equation}
\min_{A\in\mathcal{A},x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n : Ax=b \}
\end{equation}
The set $\mathcal{A}$ is such that the problem can equivalently be stated as:
\begin{equation}
\min_{\mu\in\mathbb{R}^m,x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \{x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n : \mu_i (r_i^Tx)=b_i \; (i=1,\ldots,m), \;Q\mu>q \}
\end{equation}

Are there some known ways to do this?
Maybe I can use a modification of the simplex method?

Thanks for any ideas and information.

Comment: Some ideas: Since $Ax=b$ has a unique solution $>0$, then $A$ is invertible. This means you're trying to minimize $e^TA^{-1}b$ over $A$

Comment: What is your representation of the convex set for A?

Comment: If $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$, then $(\alpha A+ (1-\alpha) B) \in \mathcal{A}$, for any $\alpha \in [0, 1]$

Comment: @Oleg that is the definition of convexity. How is the set $\mathcal{A}$ defined though?

Comment: Roughly speaking, $\mathcal{A} = \{A: a_{i,j} = r_{i,j}\mu_i,\}  $,  where $r_{i,j}$ are fixed,  $Q\mu>q$.

Comment: Presuming everything except $x$ and $\mu$ is input data, and that you change $Q\mu \gt q$ to a non-strict inequality $Q\mu \ge q+ d$, where $d$ is a small number you input, this looks like a standard Linear Programming problem. Use the optimization modeling system and/or solver of your choice to enter pretty much as written. The vector $x$ concatenated with $\mu$ will be your optimization variable. Many modeling systems let you declare them as separate variables, and take care of concatenation for you under the hood, so that you can enter the problem in a more natural and less error-prone way.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, but then there arise the nonlinear constraints $\mu_i(r_i^Tx)=b_i$, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Oleg Sorry about that, you're right.  Those are bilinear equality constraints, which are non-convex.  Perhaps there is a more clever formulation, but if not, you could try putting it in a global solver such as BARON, however, I don;t know how long it will take to run.  What values of m and n are you interested in?  If you're content with a local minimum, you could use a nonlinear non-convex solver, such as IPOPT, FMINCON, KNITRO, SNOPT, or others.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, thanks for the solvers.  I consider cases where $n,m<1000$.

Comment: @Oleg There's a big difference between 2 and 999, especially for a global solver.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, yes, I just need test it.